# Eclipse 'Installing Software' - chmod failed

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm new to Java and Eclipse and I'm not sure what this error message means:

*An error occurred while installing the items session context was:

> (profile=epp.package.java,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install,
>   operand=null --> [R]com.sap.ide.support.feature_root.gtk.linux.x86_64
>   1.11.1, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.ChmodAction).
>   The action chmod failed - file
>   /opt/eclipse/collectSupportInformation.sh does not exist*

This happened while I was trying to install a ui tool. I've used `Help->Install New Software` before and it worked just fine then but now I'm getting this error no matter what I'm trying to install (I tried several different tools). What am I supposed to do?

I'm using Eclipse Luna on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below steps:-

1) Restart your eclipse by using clean flag -> ./eclipse -clean
2) Turn off usage data collection by going to preference->usage data collection-> turn off
3) make sure the user who is running eclipse having read write permission to dir /opt/eclipse, or just execute the command chmod -R 777 /opt/eclipse (Once problem is resolved you can again change the proper mode, 777 is just for trying to fix the issue).

Hope it will help you to resolve the issue.Please update if you facing any issue to follow the above steps.

Comment: @alekhris Accepting the answer would help

Comment: @prashantthakre I'm having exactly the same problem, also on Ubuntu 14.04 but the usage data collection is not available under the preferences (using Eclipse Kepler). Any other idea I can try?

Comment: @prashantthakre Correction: the shell file location is different in my case. It tries to start /usr/lib/<eclipse dir>/collectSupportInformation.sh, not in /opt/eclipse.

Answer (score 7):

I was having this issue on my mac. I got it working by moving the Eclipse app to the Applications folder (I was running it from Downloads).

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've got something similar but under Windows 8.1 and the fix was to close the Eclipse IDE and then "Run as Administrator", then run the updates!

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading full package through eclipse.org direct link instead of through Installer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was "opening with Archiver" instead of saving first to disk. If first I save the tar.gz to disk, then untar it and run the eclipse-inst, all is fine

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating an empty script (using the path found in the error).
You probably need to run this as root:

```
echo #!/bin/sh >/usr/lib/eclipse/collectSupportInformation.sh
chmod +x /usr/lib/eclipse/collectSupportInformation.sh
```