# Updating software failed in luna eclipse 4.4.0

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am using `help->check for updates` in my luna eclipse 4.4.0 and I got one update for

**Eclipse IDE for Java EE Develppers  4.4.2.20150219-0708 epp.package.jee**

And at the end it is not getting updated and showing me the below error.

```
An error occurred while installing the items
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Install, operand=null --> [R]org.eclipse.rcp.configuration_root.win32.win32.x86_64 1.0.3.v20150204-1745, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.ChmodAction).
The action chmod failed - file D:\Work\eclipse_jee_luna_r\eclipse\eclipse.exe does not exist
```

How can I solve this update issue?

Comment: Visit Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25091732/eclipse-installing-software-chmod-failed

Comment: But it is in ubuntu.I am using windows 8.1.I had tried the 2nd answer not worked

Comment: I am not getting the preferences->usage data collection.I have only one workspace.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably a dead question but I had the same issue updating from 4.4.1 to 4.4.2

Anti-Virus was the issue.  I turned off McAfee's real time scanning, did the update without issue and turned real time scanning back on.

Hope this helps the next person.